# second order linear equation (nonhomogeneous)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the nonhomogeneous differential equation

$$y'' + 4y =\sin(\alpha t).$$

For all possible real $\alpha$ decide which values of $\alpha$ gives a limited amount of solutions.

I found the homogeneous solution which yields: $y_h= C_1\sin(2t) + C_2\cos(2t)$

Any tips/solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by limited amount of solutions?

Comment: doesnt this get infinite amount of solutions since I have alpha? or something?

Comment: So now you need to find a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation. This will be of the form $A\sin(at)+B\cos(at)$ where you work out the values of $A$ and $B$ by substituting into the equation, except that if $a=2$ then you have to use $t(A\sin(at)+B\cos(at))$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$y=sin(\alpha t)$ is a solution of $$\alpha^2y+y''=0$$
$$(D^2+\alpha^2)y=0$$ so apply

$$(D^2+\alpha^2)(y''+4y)=(D^2+\alpha^2)(sin(\alpha t))$$
$$(D^2+\alpha^2)(D^2+4)(y)=0$$
$$(D^4+(\alpha^2+4)D^2+4\alpha^2)y=0 $$

Thus, we have a homogenius equation with characterestic polynomial $$\lambda^4+(\alpha^2+4)\lambda^2+4\alpha^2=0 $$

**Note:** I used the $D$ as derivative operator.